# How to avoid switch case in factory

Tags: c#

I have this factory class which converts a `Foo` into a list of `Bar` objects.  Foo is a very complex object which I flatten into a list of simple `Bar` objects.  There are about 60 different bits of data that could be transformed from a `Foo` into a `Bar`.  The following implementation works but there's definite scope for improvement here.

```
public class FooToBarsConverter
{
    public List<Bar> Convert(Foo foo)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(BarTypeEnum))
            .Cast<BarTypeEnum>()
            .Select(barType => CreateBar(foo, barType))
            .Where(newBar => newBar != null)
            .ToList();
    }


    public Bar CreateBar(Foo foo, BarTypeEnum barType)
    {
        switch (barType)
        {
            case BarTypeEnum.TypeA:
                return CreateTypeA(foo);

            case BarTypeEnum.TypeB:
                return CreateTypeB(foo);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Bar CreateTypeA(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar(...);
    }

    private Bar CreateTypeB(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar(...);
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid having to write a new case to the switch every time a new BarType is added.  Perhaps a dictionary of types and delegate functions but that would still require a mapping of sorts?  Is there any feature of the language that I can exploit to avoid this switch case a make the compiler choose the create create function?

---

Assuming you don't mind the factory methods being statics this does neaten it up a bit without needing the cruft of having to create ~60 more sub-classes to get the type system to do the work for me.  I think the statics aren't needed if you make it a `func` with the factory as well but I've not got that far yet.  The statics don't particularly bother me with it just being data transposition

```
private static readonly IDictionary<BarTypeEnum, Func<Foo, Bar>>
  CreateLookup = new Dictionary<BarTypeEnum, Func<Foo, Bar>>
   {
       { BarTypeEnum.TypeA, CreateTypeA },
       { BarTypeEnum.TypeB, CreateTypeB }
   };

 public Bar Create(Foo foo, BarTypeEnum barType)
 {
     Func<Foo, Bar> createDelegate;
     CreateLookup.TryGetValue(barType, out createDelegate);
     return createDelegate != null ? createDelegate(foo) : null;
 }

 private static Bar CreateTypeA(Foo foo) { ... }
 private static Bar CreateTypeB(Foo foo) { ... }
```

Comment: You would have to update to add a new `CreateBarType` method anyway, what harm is an extra case statement going to do? For me, it's pretty readable and anything else could *potentially* sacrifice that.

Comment: Could you pass in the actual type instead of an enum that represents the type? That way create bar could just be `return Activator.CreateInstance(barType, new object[] { foo })`.

Comment: @axblount The problem is I only have one `Bar` object which is something like `new Bar { Id = 123, Type = barType, Data1 = "xyz", Data2 = "ghj" }`.  I guess I could create a strongly typed version of each `BarType` which inherits from Bar then use that like this in the `Create<BarTypeA>`

Comment: I would love someone to come up with a better way, but I don't think it exists. Uncle Bob even surrenders to a switch statement usage in factories, if you have read his books you probably noticed he loathes switch statements. I would love some whiz to come on and prove me wrong.

Comment: What about *Foo*, is this something unchangeable, like *Bar*? How it is being used in each *Create...* method?

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<BarTypeEnum, Func<Bar>>`. That way, all the information is packed in the initializer for this dictionary.

Comment: I've written out a simple solution using the dictionary above

Comment: Is the example accurate to the extent where each *type* of `Bar` is just a different constructor being called? i.e. it's not like `CreateTypeX` is going to instantiate like `BarX`?

Comment: There is only one type of `Bar` - it is a generic object which can represent many objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any feature of the language that I can exploit to avoid this switch case a make the compiler choose the create create function?

Yes. It's called polymorphism

Check this video: [Jimmy Bogard - Crafting Wicked Domain Models](http://vimeo.com/43598193) on how an enum could be converted into a polimorhic class hierachy.

Basically you create an abstract class called BarTypeEnum that feels like an enum and create n derived types, one for each enum value. Then you could have this method

```
public abstract Bar CreateBar(Foo foo);
```

and override it in every subclass each returning a diferent subtype of Bar

e.g.

```
public override Bar CreateBar(Foo foo)
{
    return CreateTypeA(foo);
}
```

BTW: The enumeration class he talks about is on NuGet as the [NuGet package Enumeration](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Enumeration)

**EDIT**
I just checked and the nuget package class is not the same as the video. It is a Generic, nonpolimorphic way to implement it though

Comment: Nice solution, I guess this way it really enforces SRP.  It just seems like overkill creating all those sub-classes when the enum already exists and is the type identifier for the database.  I guess it might make more sense to me if I was going to have all 60 tables in the database and and aggregate view but I don't want to do that particularly.

Answer (score 1):

Not a huge fan of this because it's a bit hard to read, but you can define a custom attribute, mapping each enum value to its method. You'd use reflection to find and execute the appropriate method.

```
public class BarChooserAttribute : Attribute
{
    public BarChooserAttribute(BarTypeEnum barType) { BarType = barType; }
    public BarTypeEnum BarType { get; set; }
}

public static class CreateBarMethods
{
    [BarChooser(BarTypeEnum.TypeA)]
    public static Bar CreateTypeA(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar { Message = "A" };
    }

    [BarChooser(BarTypeEnum.TypeB)]
    public static Bar CreateTypeB(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar { Message = "B" };
    }
}

public static Bar CreateBar(Foo foo, BarTypeEnum barType)
{
    var methodWrapper = typeof(CreateBarMethods).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Select(m => new { Method = m, Att = (BarChooserAttribute)m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BarChooserAttribute), false).Single() })
        .Single(x => x.Att.BarType == barType);
    return (Bar)methodWrapper.Method.Invoke(null, new[] { foo });
}
```

To improve performance, you can map the methods into a dictionary one time and retrieve them from the dictionary each time. Additionally, you can use expression trees to compile the methods into lambda expressions, so you only have to do reflection once instead of each time you make the call. Significant performance improvements, to get significantly harder-to-read code, so it's a trade-off.

Comment: I like this solution, good to know that there's performance enhancements available if required. Expression trees is one of those things that I think that I really should learn more about.

Comment: If you do start looking into expression trees, be prepared to bang your head on the wall for awhile. Even with a tutorial, the syntax is not intuitive, and it's very easy to make a mistake that the compiler or runtime will not help with. I probably read a dozen or so tutorials, but still resort to trial-and-error every time I attempt to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't mind a `switch` in a factory method, it's readable, it's neat and doesn't sarcrafice the end goal of what a factory method is for - keeping the initialization code together.

However, that being said, I wonder if a custom attribute could tidy this up a bit for you. Going on the assumption all the `CreateBarX` methods create an instance of `Bar` initializing the specific properties from `Foo`.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class FooConverter : System.Attribute
{
    public string Parameters;

    public Bar GetInstance(Foo foo)
    {
        var propNames = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters) ? new string[] { } : Parameters.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
        var parameters = foo.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => propNames.Contains(x.Name)).Select(x => x.GetValue(foo));
        return (Bar)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Bar), parameters.ToArray());
    }
}

// extension helpers
public static class EnumExt
{
    public static Bar GetInstance(this BarTypeEnum value, Foo foo)
    {
        var converterAttr = value.GetAttribute<FooConverter>();
        return converterAttr != null ? converterAttr.GetInstance(foo) : null;
    }

    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this System.Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        var attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? (T)attributes[0] : default(T);
    }   
}
```

Which would allow you to do

```
public enum BarTypeEnum
{
    [FooConverter] // no properties mapped
    TypeA,
    [FooConverter(Parameters="Prop1")] // map Prop1 from Foo to Bar
    TypeB,
    TypeC, // no instance
    [FooConverter(Parameters="Prop1, Prop2")] // map Prop1/2 from Foo to Bar
    TypeD, 
    TypeE // no instance
}

public List<Bar> Convert(Foo foo)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(BarTypeEnum))
        .Cast<BarTypeEnum>()
        .Select(barType => barType.GetInstance(foo))
        .Where(newBar => newBar != null)
        .ToList();
}
```

And that's all you need!

However, there are some limitations to this approach with respect to the parameter injection, `CreateInstance` will only match the constructor based on a signature which matches the data type i.e.

```
 // this will call Bar(string prop1, string prop2)
 Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Bar), new object[] { "Property1", "Property2" });

 // where as this will car Bar(string prop1)
 Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Bar), new object[] { "Property2" });
```

The ordering is important as well

```
 // this will call Bar(string prop1, string prop2) so Prop1 = "Property2"
 Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Bar), new object[] { "Property2", "Property1" });
```

However, there are ways around this - for the most part this will probably work well.

Answer (score 0):

I hate 'case's and I like Generics therefore I slightly changed interface of FooToBarsConverter:

```
public interface IFooToBarsConverter
{
    List<Bar> Convert(Foo foo);
    Bar CreateBar<TBarType>(Foo foo) where TBarType : Bar;
}
```

There is an implementation:

```
public class FooToBarsConverter : IFooToBarsConverter
{
    public List<Bar> Convert(Foo foo)
    {
        return new List<Type>
        {
            typeof(Bar.BarA),
            typeof(Bar.BarB)
        }.Select(it => CreateBar(foo, it))
        .ToList();
    }

    public Bar CreateBar<T>(Foo foo)
        where T : Bar
    {
        return CreateBar(foo, typeof(T));
    }

    private Bar CreateBar(Foo foo, Type barType)
    {
        return typeof(Bar).IsAssignableFrom(barType)
            ? (Bar)Activator.CreateInstance(barType, foo)
            : null;
    }
}

public class Foo
{
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    private Bar(Foo foo)
    {

    }

    public class BarA : Bar
    {
        public BarA(Foo foo)
            : base(foo)
        {
        }
    }

    public class BarB : Bar
    {
        public BarB(Foo foo)
            : base(foo)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

... and a test that tests it:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // arrange
        var foo = new Foo();
        var target = new FooToBarsConverter();

        // act + assert
        var list = target.Convert(foo);
        list.Should().HaveCount(2);
        list.Should().NotContainNulls();

        var typeA = target.CreateBar<Bar.BarA>(foo);
        typeA.Should().BeAssignableTo<Bar.BarA>();

        var typeB = target.CreateBar<Bar.BarB>(foo);
        typeB.Should().BeAssignableTo<Bar.BarB>();
    }
```